# How can I check if asp:Checkbox is checked and show or hide It using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `asp:checkbox` and a `asp:textbox` on my aspx page , I want to know show the textbox when the checkbox is checked and hide it if the checkbox is unckecked using javascript , I really apprecieatee anyone who could help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can uee this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function radio_yes(){
if(document.getElementById("c1").checked==true)
        document.getElementById("atext").style.visibility="visible";
        else
        document.getElementById("atext").style.visibility="hidden";}
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id = "c1" name="subscriptions" onclick = "radio_yes();radio_uncheck();"  value="CorporateEmails"/>
    Corporate Press Release Emails<br />
<input type="text" id="atext">
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these render on the browser as a normal checkbox and textarea, then you can get notification of when the checkbox is ticked or unticked using its [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click) event:

```
$("selector_for_the_checkbox").click(function() {
    // ...handle the event here...
});
```

Within the event handler, `this` will refer to the raw checkbox element (not a jQuery wrapper for it).

To show a hidden element with jQuery, you use [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show); to hide one, you use [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide). You can also use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to show or hide the element on the basis of its current state or a flag you pass in. So:

```
$("selector_for_the_checkbox").click(function() {
    $("selector_for_the_textarea").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

It's **well worth** spending an hour (that's all it takes) reading through the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end.

Comment: Considering the fact that ASP.NET renders not-entirely trivial HTML for a CheckBox (span + label-for + input) I bet the question is about the actual selector :)

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleTextBox(bEnable, textBoxID) {
        document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and your aspx would be like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkApplied" runat="server" onclick="javascript:toggleTextBox(this.checked, 'txtAmount'); />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and if your client side id differs, you can bind it from server side like this:

```
chkApplied.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:toggleTextBox(this.checked, '" + txtAmount.ClientID + "');");
```